# php static function, query database

Tags: php, mysql, methods, pdo, static

I would like to know abit more about `static`. If i got my class with some static functions in it:

```
<?php
class Input {
public function exists($type = 'post') {
    switch($type) {
        case 'post':
            return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
        break;
        case 'get':
            return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }
}

public static function get($item) {
    if(isset($_POST[$item])) {
        return $_POST[$item];
    } else if(isset($_GET[$item])) {
        return $_GET[$item];
    }
    return '';
}
}
```

and `spl_autoload_register` i can access the functions using Input::get($item); while with non static functions i need to instance it with, `$input = new Input();` and can then access a function by using $input->exists();

So, i dont get the difference. Can i query a database from a `static` method? does `__constructor` work?

I cant find any clear answer online.

Comment: Not sure what you are really asking here. If you don’t know what static means and what impact it has, then go read up on it in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: This is really basic and too broad a topic to be answered here. You should read some documentation. If you still have questions then, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use static methods when they're not dependent on the properties of any particular object instance. You use non-static methods when they need to refer to the object's properties.

You can query a database from any type of method. The choice depends on the way your class is designed. For instance, if you design the class so that each object can have a different database connection property, you'll need to use a non-static method to query the database so that it will use that object's connection. But if the connection is a static property of the class, you can do it in a static method.